# D3 GeoPath Curve

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have been using d3 line to draw onto a map I have built. I have now switched to using a d3 geopath so that it follows the curvature of the earth but I have not been able to curve the corners.

Whilst using a d3 line, I was able to specify `.curve(d3.curveCatmullRom)`, is there an equivalent for geopath?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://turfjs.org/docs/#bezier?